# Error loading photo

Tags: java, android, loading, photo, photos

Good morning!
I am new to this forum.
I'm making an app for Android.

I have a photo gallery that I see is within a `GridView`.

Some photos charging me with no problems, while others give me this error:

> ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker)

I also tried to change the format of those photos but nothing.

The photos are all taken from the same site.

I think the problem is in particular images.

This is the vector where there are several url of the photo

```
public final static String[] images = new String[]{"link1.jpg", "link2.jpg", ...};
```

I need help because I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you need to add MUCH MORE details to your question. We don't even know what language you are talking about (is this a website? Desktop App? We don't know.). Also add code examples to your question illustrating what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: You still need to post more information, we need to see the code/the error's stack trace.